# Simple Client/Server Socket based on Netbeans

Tags: java, sockets, netbeans, client

I'm a beginner and i   wrote a simple client server socket model in netbeans
- The server is a simple is listing on port 1119 and receive messages from the client and print them ( Console mod) .
- The client is Based on netbeans Form model and has a text field and two buttons (Connect and send ) like in the image :

http://s24.postimg.org/on6svgjpx/sss.jpg

i should press connect once and then when i type a message in the text field and press send it send it to the server which should print it ok , now at the beginning it works ,but after that it doesn't send anything and i need to press connect again and send to send it , the thing i want is ti make the client press connect once and only once and after that i can send messages when press send not using the connect again !!!!  so please help me how to do that !!!

here is the simple codes :

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {


   public static void main(String args []) throws IOException
    {
      System.out.println("Starting Server ....");
       ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(1119);
       while(true){
       Socket connection=ss.accept();
    DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String s=br.readLine();
System.out.println(s+"\n");
        }
   }
}
```

the client code (it is netbeans IDE ):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class test extends javax.swing.JFrame {
DataOutputStream dout;
BufferedReader br;
Socket cs=null;
    /** Creates new form test */
    public test() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jButton1.setText("Send");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("Connect");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(288, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(39, 39, 39))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 272, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addContainerGap(86, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 122, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 54, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(22, 22, 22))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            cs = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1119);
            dout=new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());

            // TODO add your handling code here:
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        try {
            dout.writeBytes(jTextField1.getText()+"\n");
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(test.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new test().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration

}
```

Answer (score 0):

what i want is ti make the client press connect once and only once and after that i can send messages when press send not using the connect again !

Change this:

```
while(true){
       Socket connection=ss.accept();//here
       DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
       BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
       String s=br.readLine();
       System.out.println(s+"\n");
}
```

To:

```
Socket connection=ss.accept();//here
while(true){
    DataOutputStream dout=new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
    String s=br.readLine();
    System.out.println(s+"\n");
        }
```

Keeping accept() in the forever loop will keep server waiting for new Connections.

Comment: thanks alot it did work , can you tell me how to server multi client ? like making a thread that server every single client by editing that code ?! 

All regards

Comment: I kind of thought you might want this. You need to create a thread that keeps listening to new connections and pass this new socket to another thread that reads incoming messages through this socket.

Comment: Check this link : http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html